# Does Apache Ignite v2.7.5 support nested join queries for non-collocated JOINS?

Tags: join, left-join, ignite, gridgain

I am trying to run the nested join query with partitioned caches but faced data loss.

Along with this can you help me understand how these checks (Allow non-collocated joins, enforce join order) works with the join. Is it mandatory to check them to work with JOINS?

PS: I have multiple questions, I am looking for some clarity on JOIN topic with these checks.

Below is the query i was trying to execute :

```
SELECT child_2.id, child_2.sales,child_2.country,
         child_2.commission,child_2.agent_name,
         child_2.created_date,child_2.created_user,
         child_2.modified_user,child_2.modified_date,
         child1.agent_name, parent.agent_name, parent.working_area 
FROM child_2  
   LEFT JOIN  
     child1 
         ON child_2.country = child1.country
   LEFT JOIN  
     parent 
         ON child1.country = parent.working_area
```

I am expecting 11 rows in the end but it is only giving me 9.[please look at this snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMXcs.jpg)

Comment: Could you please clarify how your data is collocated?

Comment: Hi,sorry for late reply.when the data is at same node is collocated but when some data is at a node and some at b node is non-collocated